# What should I do with my "hidden assumption in the zombie thought experiment" question?

Tags: support

I feel like in my question [Does the philosophical zombies question/idea contain a hidden assumption?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98675/does-the-philosophical-zombies-question-idea-contain-a-hidden-assumption) I have bit by bit over time unintentionally provided overwhelming evidence that there is a hidden assumption in the zombie question posed by Chalmers and am starting to wish, especially in light of the lukewarm response to it, that I had asked something a bit more in doubt, such as *why* the assumption is not acknowledged at all by SEP, and Chalmers, and the acknowledgement by Wikipedia seems buried in the body of the article rather than in plain view.

The problem is that there is now an answer: Ocram's short (and slightly sarcastic?) answer, which means I risk creating a chameleon question if I try to change it.

Would a new question asking this be closed as a duplicate?

Or is it okay as it is?

Should I delete some of the stuff from the question and make an answer out of it, and answer my own question?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one answer and it has no upvotes. As such, I would say it is completely okay to specify the thrust and scope of the question despite there already being one answer present.